# How to speed up splitting a column into a thoursand columns?

Tags: r, sqlite, split, large-data

I need to analyse a large dataset. For that, I need to separate a character variable into more than a thousand columns. The structure of this variable is `number$number$number$ and so on for a thousand numbers`.

My data is stored in an SQLite database. I imported it in R using RSQLite. I tried splitting this column into multiple columns using dplyr :

```
#d is a data.table with my data

d2=d %>% separate(column_to_separate, paste0("S",c(1:number_of_final_columns)))
```

It works but is taking forever. How to split this column faster (either in R or using SQLite)?

Comment: maybe try to save it as plain text and load it with data.table::fread, sep = "$"

Comment: I didn't managed to write the file (I detailled it in the edit)

Comment: try fwrite(d, "file.csv") and then fread("file.csv", sep = "$") see the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `tidyfast` package ([see here](https://tysonbarrett.com/tidyfast/)), that leverages on `data.table`. In this test, it is approximately three times faster:

```r
test <- data.frame(
  long.var = rep(paste0("V", 1:1000, "$", collapse = ""), 1000)
)
system.time({
  test |> 
    tidyr::separate(long.var, into = paste0("N", 1:1001), sep="\\$")
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.352   0.012   0.365

system.time({
  test |> 
    tidyfast::dt_separate(long.var, into = paste0("N", 1:1001), sep="\\$")
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.117   0.000   0.118
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write the file as is and then try to load it with fread, which is in general rather fast.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Prepare example
x <- matrix(rnorm(1000*10000), ncol = 1000)
dta <- data.frame(value = apply(x, 1, function(x) paste0(x, collapse = "$")))

# Run benchmark
microbenchmark::microbenchmark({
    dta_2 <- dta %>%
      separate(col = value, sep = "\\$", into = paste0("col_", 1:1000))
  },
  {
    tmp_file <- tempfile()
    fwrite(dta, tmp_file)
    dta_3 <- fread(tmp_file, sep = "$", header = FALSE)
  }, times = 3
)
```

Edit: I tested the speed and it seems faster than dt_seperate from tidyfast, but it depends on the size of your dataset.

Comment: I tested the two solutions too, and the tidyfast was way faster. Maybe it has something to do with my really limited RAM : your solution seemed to have overloaded it since my dataset is heavy.